# Mock function in Firebase local emulator

Tags: firebase, testing, google-cloud-functions, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Such as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator), I'm using local emulator (on-line) to make tests im my cloud functions.

Index.js:

```js
    var status = 200;
    exports.saveAndSendMail = functions.https.onCall( async (req, res) => {
    try{
        let jsons = req.body;

        await saveInfirestore(jsons);

        await sendMail("Data saved", jsons);

    } finally {
        closeConnection(res, status);
    }
    async function saveInfirestore(json) {
    //execute business logic and save in firestore (irrelevant for this question)
    }


    function closeConnection (res, status){
        res.sendStatus(status);
        res.end();
    }


    async function sendMail(title, message) {
    try {
       AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config_mail.json');

        // Create sendEmail params 
        var params = {
        Destination: { 
            ToAddresses: [
            'mymail@gmail.com'
            ]
        },
        Message: { /* required */
            Body: { /* required */
        Html: {
                Charset: "UTF-8", 
                Data: JSON.stringfy(message);
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                Data: title
            }
            },
        Source: '"Origin" <origin@gmail.com>',
        ReplyToAddresses: [
            'origin@gmail.com'
        ]
        };

        // Create the promise and SES service object
        var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2022-17-01'}).sendEmail(params).promise();
    }
    catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    sendPromise.then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data.MessageId);
    }).catch(
        function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
    });
  }
```

index.test.js

```js
    const { expect } = require("chai");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    
    const test = require("firebase-functions-test")({
        projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    });
    
    const myFunctions = require("../index");
    
    describe("Unit tests", () => {
      after(() => {
        test.cleanup();
      });
    
      it("test if save is correct", async () => {
        const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.saveAndSendMail);
    
          const req = {
            body: [{
              value: 5,
              name: 'mario'
            }]
          };
    
        const result = await wrapped(req);
    
        let snap = await db.collection("collection_data").get();
    
        expect(snap.size).to.eq(1);
        
        snap.forEach(doc => {
    
            let data = doc.data();
    
            expect(data.value).to.eql(5);
            expect(data.name).to.eql('mario');
        });
    
    });
```

I execute it with: firebase emulators:exec "npm run test"

I have 2 problems.

1 - When execute, I receive the error `TypeError: res.sendStatus is not a function`. If I comment `closeConnection` call in block finally (index.js), this code run perfectly and all tests and "expect" run with success. But, this correct way is mock this method or mock 'res' calls. I tried mock with something like this:

```js
       const res = {
            sendStatus: (status) => {
            },
            end: () => {
            }
          }
    
    const result = await wrapped(req, res);
```

But, I receive this error:

```
 Error: Options object {} has invalid key "sendStatus"
  at /home/linuxuser/my-project/firebase/functions/myfolder/node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:99:19
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at _checkOptionValidity (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:97:26)
  at wrapped (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:57:13)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:50:26)
  at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)
```

Problem 2:

I'm not wish receive an e-mail each time that tests executes. How I mock sendMail function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something very important to point out is that you are currently trying to use a [Firebase callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function), as shown by the function heading `functions.https.onCall(() => {});`. Since you want to work with requests and response codes, the correct type of function to use is an [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request). You would only need to change the heading in your `index.js`:

```js
exports.saveAndSendMail = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // function body
});
```

Now, your first problem can then be solved by correctly mocking the `res` object that is passed to the function (inside `index.test.js`). When testing HTTP functions, you must not use `test.wrap()` when calling the function, nor expect the result as you were doing with `const result = await wrapped(req);` This is since `Wrap` being only supported for testing `onCall` functions. You can see another snippet of how to call an HTTP function for testing in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#testing_http_functions).

```js
  it("test if save is correct", async () => {
      const req = {
        body: [{
          value: 5,
          name: 'mario'
        }]
      };

      // mocking the response object that is returned from the function:
      const res = {
        sendStatus: (code) => {
          expect(code).to.eql(200); // asserting that we get 200 back as the response code
        },
        end: () => {

        }
      };
    
    const result = await myFunctions.saveAndSendMail(req, res); // mocking a call to an HTTP function, without test.wrap()
    // rest of the function…
```

For your second problem, I haven’t used AWS SES before, but it seems [this library](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock) offers ways to mock the functions so that you won’t have to actually send emails during your tests.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. If I change onCall for onRequest, when run tests, get this error: Error: Wrap function is only available for `onCall` HTTP functions, not `onRequest`.
      at Object.wrap (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:46:15)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:29:26)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)

Comment: I keep 'onCall' and try send your 'res' sugestion. But, same error: Error: Options object {} has invalid key "sendStatus"

Comment: @vctlzac I edited my answer to make it more clear how to call the `onRequest` function, which should be the type of function to use in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for you edition. I need use wrap, because in my index.js the json data execute an especific business logic and save data in some collections based on this business rules, and I need check it. So, I need use wrap for start firebase emulator locally and so check if this data is persisted correctly in firebase.

Comment: If I not use wrap, firebase emulator not working, right?

Comment: I tested writing a document to Firestore with `saveInFirestore()` and confirmed the saved results against the expected in `index.test.js` successfully. The way to use the **Firestore emulator** inside this emulated function is to export the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable with value `localhost:8080` (or the port used by the Firestore emulator). You can check this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/776#issuecomment-751685424) for reference. Afterwards, I ran your `firebase emulators:exec “npm run test”` command from the same terminal instance.

Comment: Sorry about long time to response. I removed test.wrap and use environment variable and it works. For second problem I use https://github.com/jhnns/rewire instead of AWS SES library. Thanks for help.